# dplyr and reusable argument lists

Tags: r, dplyr

I have played around with `dplyr` a little and really like it. I am missing something though. In `plyr`, I was able to pass a functions to `ddply`and reuse it.

```
library('dplyr')
library('plyr')

fn = function(df) {
    summarise(df,
        count = length(id))
}

ddply(DF1,'group', fn)
ddply(DF2,'group', fn)
```

So I can apply a long list of recordings to multiple datasets without replicating all the arguments to `summarise`. In `dplyr`, however, I have to do this

```
dplyr::summarise(group_by(DF1,group),
    count = length(id))
dplyr::summarise(group_by(DF2,group),
    count = length(id))
```

So the arguments to `summarise` have to be repeated each time. A list of arguments with `list('.data'=DF1,'count'=length(id))` and `do.call` does not work either because `length(id)` is evaluated when I define the argument list. Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: Why do you have many small data frames instead of one big data frame?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like @RomanLustrik answer, so here's a 100% `dplyr` approach to his answer.

```
do(mylist, function(df)
   df %.%
   group_by(b) %.%
   summarise(count = n()))

## [[1]]
## Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

##   b count
## 1 b     5
## 2 a     5

## [[2]]
## Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

##   b count
## 1 b     5
## 2 a     5
```

In this answer I just tried to replicate Roman's approach but you can reuse your function (fn) :

```
fn <- function(df) {
    summarise(df,
        count = n())
}

group_by(df1, b) %.% fn()
## Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

##   b count
## 1 b     5
## 2 a     5

group_by(df2, b) %.% fn()
## Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

##   b count
## 1 b     5
## 2 a     5
```

And you can even wrap it like this

```
do(list(df1, df2), function(df) group_by(df, b) %.% fn())
```

Comment: very nice solution. I guess it's not possible to avoid copying the data.frames to a list and getting lists back? The `ddply` approach pre-saves the recodings so that they can be applied multiple times.

Comment: @user2503795 I edited my answer, check if is the expected result you were looking for.

Comment: This is exactly what I'd recommend. Thanks for saving me some typing :)

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're after?

```
df1 <- df2 <- data.frame(a = runif(10), b = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5))

library(dplyr)

mylist <- list(df1, df2)
lapply(mylist, FUN = function(x) {
  dplyr::summarise(group_by(x, b),
                   count = length(b))
})
[[1]]
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  b count
1 a     5
2 b     5

[[2]]
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  b count
1 a     5
2 b     5
```

Comment: This is analogous to the issue of when anonymous/lambda functions get applied, e.g. in Python.